# How to create a .dll from Netbeans using Linux?

Tags: linux, netbeans, dll, java-native-interface, cross-compiling

I'm working on a Linux machine (debian) 64bit and created a simple project involving JNI. The program is running fine on Linux with the created Java project and the compiled `.so` file. The goal now is to compile the C++ part of the project into a `.dll` instead of a `.so` to get it to run on Windows machines.

I read some forums and some articles like this one [Article](http://www.blogcompiler.com/2010/07/11/compile-for-windows-on-linux/), but all of those articles were about compiling from console and also didn't involve the necessary JNI includes.

I also downloaded the cross-compiler from the given article and tried to get it to run in Netbeans. Therefore I set up another `C/C++ Tool Collection` in Netbeans and told it to use the `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` compiler for both C and C++. But Netbeans is giving me some errors compiling the file, telling me the `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` compiler could not be found which is quite random I think because I selected it from the file chooser. Did any of you do something like this already, building a `.ddl` from Netbeans running on Linux? If yes, how did you get it to work?

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc: not found
bproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:66: recipe for target 'build/Debug/GNU_1-Linux-x86/WrapperCpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/GNU_1-Linux-x86/WrapperCpp.o] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:59: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

@Edit: I'm a step further now: I installed the correct mingw32 tools: `sudo apt-get install mingw32`. The programm does now compile without errors using the `i586-mingw32msvc-g++` compiler but it still results in a `.so` instead of a `.dll`. I guess it has something to do with the `make command` but I haven't found anything about that yet.